# Complex TTITLE expressions in Oracle SQLPlus reports

Tags: oracle, reporting, sqlplus

I'm writing a SQLPlus report in which the recurring header contains an address for a business, followed by several relevant rows regarding that business, followed by the address for the next business:

```
BOB'S GUITARS 
123 SESAME STREET 
NEW YORK, NY 10001

customer name   last purchase date   last purchase amount
-------------   ------------------   --------------------

DAVE'S CIGARS 
456 MOCKINGBIRD LANE 
WASHINGTON, DC 12345

customer name   last purchase date   last purchase amount
-------------   ------------------   --------------------
```

The problem is this:

Some of those businesses have multi-line addresses, while others do not.

I can handle the basic case with something like
`TTITLE CENTER BUSINESSNAME SKIP 1 CENTER ADDR1 SKIP 1 CENTER CITY`

(where "CITY" is a variable containing city, state, and zip)

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to put "add the second address line if ADDR2 is not null" without risking a blank line between ADDR1 and CITY.

In other words, I don't want

```
BOB'S GUITARS
123 SESAME STREET

NEW YORK, NY 10001
```

in order to support

```
DAVE'S CIGARS
456 MOCKINGBIRD LANE
SUITE 101
WASHINGTON, DC 12345
```

**EDIT / ADDITION**:
The suggestion of the combination of nvl and decode was the right first step, but now I've run into the problem that the two-line "line" in question exceeds the report's LINEWIDTH, and therefore gets truncated to LINEWIDTH character.  Here's the code I'm using to generate that line. Remember that both lines must be centered:

```
SELECT RPAD(' ', (79 - length(trim(address)))/2) 
  || trim(address) 
  || decode(nvl(trim(address_2), '='), '=', '', 
    CHR(10) 
    || RPAD(' ', (79 - length(trim(address_2)))/2, '-') 
    || trim(address_2) || ' ') ADDR1 from business
```

Comment: If this should be moved to a different SE site, please let me know, I'm happy to ask it elsewhere if that's appropriate.

Comment: Can't you just define a variable concatenating the second ADDR_2 to ADDR_1? 
If so i can figure a way to add the content only if it exists using DECODE and NVL

Comment: I can do that, but I need a linebreak between them, and need them both centered. Not sure how to cram that stuff into the variable or the TTITLE declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consideration of the docs and analysis, it appears that this can't be done. The (non-technical) solution was to press the business owners to accept a formatting that SQL*Plus could actually generate. They are satisfied with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you can define the address variable that will either contains the addr_1 or addr1+addr_2 if addr_2 is present. This would be the select for this variable:

select addr1 || decode(nvl(addr_2,'='),'=',' ', CHR(10) || addr_2) from table

CHR (10) is line break!!

---

Trying to complete my suggestion. (you don't need to handle manually the padding)

You need to define a column and use alias in the select as well as temp variable

```
COLUMN NEW_ADDR new_value N_ADDR noprint
TTITLE CENTER BUSINESSNAME SKIP 1 CENTER N_ADDR SKIP 1 CENTER CITY
-- I suppose you have some break on businessname command here 
BREAK ON BUSINESSNAME ON NEW_ADDR .... 
SELECT ...., ADDRESS || DECODE (NVL(ADDRESS_2,'='),'=','',CHR(10)||ADDRESS_2) AS NEW_ADDR  FROM BUSINESS
```

Also i suggest you to look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm

Comment: This should work -- but I suspect that I will have to add spaces to pad, to center the address lines correctly.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Nope -- doesn't quite work after all.  The generated line is longer than the LINESIZE variable, which isn't permitted, apparently.  And tweaking LINESIZE screws other stuff up.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect, I'm afraid.  If I don't manually handle the padding, the formatting is wrong (TTITLE treats CHR(10) as a single character, so centers the first line at the wrong column, and doesn't center the second line at all).

Comment: And I've looked at that Oracle doc at great length. Thanks, though, as future readers might get some value out of it.